# How can i make the picture zoom in with css when my picture is 100% width in a bootstrap column?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

How can i make the picture zoom in with CSS when my picture is 100% width in a bootstrap column? With my code below, it seems to transition outside the frame.

```css
.frame {
  width: 100%;
  height: 75%
  overflow: hidden;
}
.zoomin img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 75%
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.zoomin img:hover {
  width: 105%;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="zoomin frame">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/abstract/1/" title="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How would you prefer it to function? Do you want parts of the image that go beyond its container to be hidden/cropped?

Comment: It seems that there are syntax errors in your CSS. Each `height: 75%` declaration needs a semicolon at the end to differentiate it from the next declaration in the ruleset. In your current code, the missing semicolon in the `.frame` ruleset causes the `overflow` declaration not to work.

Comment: thats corect i want it hidden.

Comment: i fixed the syntax but the height skews the picture. how would i put a fixed height on it but have it responsive to to different screen sizes (hence why i put %).

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for, but you can just not specify the height. Setting only the width will keep the image's original proportions intact. [Example here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lydsdj4a/). Do you want the height not to change upon zooming?

Comment: Thats right, i want the height to stay aswell or else it moves the content below it down. i have currently added a fixed height in pixels to keep its height but then when i resize the screen it skews the image.

Comment: in your example the height changes on hover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need change your image size, you can set transform: scale to zoom them.

```css
.frame {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
  overflow: hidden;
}
.zoomin img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
   -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.zoomin img:hover {
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="zoomin frame">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/abstract/1/" title="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice solution! For further reference, see [transform @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform).